# Google Analytics Code as Coffeescript Class

Tags: coffeescript

How would I go about creating a coffeescript class that I can use in my Rails application?

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-XX', 'example.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be correct it should be:

```
((i, s, o, g, r, a, m) ->
    i["GoogleAnalyticsObject"] = r
    i[r] = i[r] or ->
      (i[r].q = i[r].q or []).push arguments

    i[r].l = 1 * new Date()

    a = s.createElement(o)
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]

    a.async = 1
    a.src = g
    m.parentNode.insertBefore a, m
  ) window, document, "script", "//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js", "ga"
```

**arguments_** doesn't make sense, it should be **arguments**. See the following link for the meaning of the arguments keyword

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the good [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) to make sure your coffee code will be interpreted properly and to help you to write the coffee version of the JS.

This analytics code became right as @Kim already answered.

Comment: Bad luck because in that case js2coffee replaces arguments with a arguments_ variable which doesn't work.